# How to disable auto-capitalization when adding new contact?

Tags: 8.1, keyboard

In keyboard settings, I've disabled the "capitalize first letter..." option. But everytime I type a new contact name, it capitalizes the first letter. How do I disable this?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware, there is no way to do this. It is built into the OS and cannot be changed. You could create a feature suggestion [here](http://www.windowsphone.uservoice.com).

Answer (score -1):

Goto Settings-->Keyboard-->Tap the first keyboard(default) and uncheck "Capitalize the first letter of a sentence". This should work. Works fine with me. Which keyboard do you use?

Comment: Didn't downvote but this will not solve the problem. Capitalizing should happen, only not when adding a new contact.

Comment: l can't stop auto capitalize please help it is in the kybourd but l can't fined the keybord sittings at all l can find themes only and sittings that say language and show suggestion that is only but l want to stop auto capitalize.